# How to restore deleted OEM partition that is "still there"?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, oem, partition-recovery, diskpart

I made the mistake of deleting Windows 8 OEM Recovery partition instead of just making it inactive.

I used diskpart:

```
select partition n
delete partition
```

Now I see the unassigned space in the Disk Management utility (but not in the diskpart).

My guess is that I can create a partition in this space (as nothing was done to it yet) and somehow mark that partition as OEM.

Am I right? Either way, how can I restore my OEM partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have just deleted descriptor of the partition from MBR, but data remains untouched.

In that case, just use software that can restore MBR by searching for lost partitions.

There are many tools: [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=recover+lost+partitions+windows+8)

Comment: Thanks. I have used one of the programs from the link and just restored the lost partition.

Comment: "Google it" is rarely a good answer. In the future, please point the OP directly to a solution.

Comment: @slhck ok, but often valid keywords for google is a real problem)

Comment: I googled it and found this answer

Answer (score -1):

The short of it is to use the Windows 8 disk manager. Instructions on how to access it can be found here http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/disk-management-windows-8.htm, but the short of *that* is to go into computer management->disk management.

**Update**

Once in disk management, Create a new simple volume, http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition.

Comment: Will doing this keep the underlying files untouched? How to make such partition OEM one?

Comment: @sthlm58 **NO, it will blow away all files on that partition**. I'm afraid if you want them back now you will have to use a tool such as [PC Tools File Recover](http://www.pctools.com/file-recover/) to get them back, but it's imperative that you don't do anything else to that partition at this point. Also, that partition is only if you want an OEM recovery, which impo hardly does any good with all the bloatware they put on machines nowadays anyway. If you have your own copy of Windows and back your own files up then I say do away with it.

Answer (score -1):

If you got any disk with your computer (recovery), use that to install.

In my case I upgraded my Windows from 7 to 8. I didn't like 8 though. Now I wanted to restore my computer to Windows 7 but the recovery partition was nowhere to be seen.

So I used recovery disks to install Windows 7 again and that helped:  After installation I was able to see the recovery partition and it worked too.